# Shortest program that demonstrates a language's complete syntax

Tags: code-golf

### The Challenge

Write the shortest possible program that demonstrates a programming language's entire syntax: statements, expressions, operators, reserved words, etc.

Take the language's grammar (usually in [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)) and create a program that uses all of it.

The program doesn't have to do anything particularly useful, but if it does that's a bonus :)

### Rules

- You must use all of the language's syntax: every type of statement, expression, operator, keyword, etc the language defines.
- It must be able to be run with no dependencies, except for the standard library included with the language (it doesn't need to use the entire standard lib though).
- Include a link to the language spec you used (e.g. here is [the Python 2.7 grammar](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/grammar.html)).

Comment: I think the Turing Tarpit entries below demonstrate pretty clearly what a fuzzy idea "complete syntax" is. I'm not sure that this is going anywhere.

Comment: Here's one on c#: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/05/11/updated-c-all-in-one-file.aspx Very very long because the specification is very big. It also tests things like very long identifiers, which the spec says it needs to handle. Meant to be a stress test for the parse.

Comment: @dmckee I had a feeling it was going to go that way. Any suggestions on how it could be less fuzzy?

Comment: Not really. Minimal languages are minimal. A nop program written for a [oisc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer) would be three words. Define the machine word as a octet and you have a tree byte program, though the machine won't be capable of much.

Comment: I wonder if there is code coverage tool for BNF grammars. I can imagine modifying parser generations like yacc and JavaCC to report grammar coverage.

Comment: damnit.... java and its banned goto keyword thats blocked in the spec but not used. also native modifier for methods

Comment: My language of choice is C++, but I ain't even gonna try ._.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem to omit `goto` and `const` for Java, as the two keywords can't be used in valid source code.

Speaking of `const`, why isn't it treated like `final`?

Comment: I started with a C++ answer, but calculated that I would be unable to finish it before the heat-death of the universe

Answer (score 9):

### Jot (2 chars)

```
10
```

http://semarch.linguistics.fas.nyu.edu/barker/Iota/#Goedel

Answer (score 5):

### Brainfuck:

```
.[->+<],
```

with the syntax being:

```
S=> '.'S|','S|'>'S|'<'S|'-'S|'+'S|'['S']'S|emptyStr
```

Answer (score 5):

### HQ9+ (4 chars)

```
HQ9+
```

It will print Hello World, then Quine, then 99 bottles of beer on the wall and then increment accumulator.

Comment: Is that really a language? Seems that it doesn't have any logic?

Comment: It isn't Turing complete, but is called "programming language" http://esolangs.org/wiki/HQ9+

Answer (score 5):

### Unary 1

```
0
```

With the syntax being

```
P => 0+
```

(syntax is technically more complicated, but I'm too lazy to figure out binary to unary conversion as an EBNF)

Answer (score 5):

## Ook

```
Ook! Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook!
```

Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook! Ook! Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook! Ook. Ook. Ook? Ook. Ook. Ook! Ook.

Comment: Flippin' Ook.  *shakes his head*

Comment: I finished doing that. Let me know if anyone can compile it.

Comment: I think you should omit the output. Since the brainfuck poster didn't post theirs. It'd be easier to scroll down this page.

Comment: @mbomb007 The output?

Comment: The first line is your program. So what's the long part?

Comment: Your program is identical to the brainfuck one. So why does your post take so much more space?

Comment: @mbomb007 The other program under it takes up more space.

Answer (score 4):

### SK combinator calculus (4 chars)

```
K(S)
```

Grammar:

```
E ::= K | S | (E) | EE |
```

Answer (score 2):

### Lambda calculus (9 chars)

```
λx. (x y)
```

#### Grammar

```
E ::= Letter | (E E) | 'λ' Letter '. ' E
Letter ::= 'a' | 'b' | ... | 'z'
```

Looks how much more verbose than SK this is!

Answer (score 2):

## Lisp (2 chars)

```
()
```

Of course, there are built in functions, such as `defun` and the basic arithmetic functions, but again, those are FUNCTIONS.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2 (13 chars)

Not sure if this is allowed:

```
exec(input())
```

**Example 1:**

Input: `'print "Hello World!"'`

Output: `Hello World!`

**Example 2:**

Input: `'import math; print math.pi'`

Output: `3.14159265359`

Comment: +1 Most people don't like loopholes for some reason.

Comment: The challenge says it "doesn't have to do anything particularly useful, but if it does that's a bonus". This does *everything* useful, although I'm not sure it meets the requirement that says that "[y]ou must use all of the language's syntax".

Comment: Is it *you*, though, who's using all of the syntax, or the user?

Comment: The code does not contain all of the elements of Python's syntax. It only contains two built-in function calls. The *code* is not dependent on user input; what it *does* is.

Answer (score 1):

## Blub

```
Blub! Blub. Blub! Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub!
```

Output:

```
Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub! Blub! Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub! Blub! Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub. Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub. Blub. Blub? Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub! Blub.
```

Comment: Also, this page: http://esolangs.org/wiki/TrivialBrainfuckSubstitution says "There are of course, infinitely many members not listed here." So please don't post anymore trivially substitutable programs/languages.

Answer (score 0):

## [Seed](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Seed), 3 chars

```
5 7
```

This seeds a [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) with the number 7 and uses it to create a 5-character Befunge program.